# Dbeaver with sql server how to set multiple variables in one run?

Tags: sql-server, variables, dbeaver

```
@set test10 = 5
select ${test10}
```

if i run this in dbeaver it gives me 5. However if i change to 7 it does not work if i select both lines together. Is that some kind of joke?

I did also read about changing Dbeaver settings:
[image: dbeaver settings for parameters]

Which is actually set as above screenshot.

as mentioned by larnu i changed the query to following:

```
DECLARE @test1 int, @test2 int;
SET @test1 = 11;
SET @test2 = 22;
SELECT @test1, @test2;
```

which is now prompting a window every time i run the query:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Same behavior if i want to define 2 variables at the top of the query:

```
@set test10 = 7
@set test11 = 8
select ${test10}, ${test11}
```

It does only work if i run line 1 then line 2 where after i can finally see the changes made by running line 3.

I was only finding split parts of explanations in the documentation and on Stack overflow so far

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? That isn't valid T-SQL and DBeaver is just an IDE. In T-SQL, variables are created with `DECLARE` and the names begin with an `@`. For example `DECLARE @V1 int, @V2 varchar(2); SET @V1 = 1; SET @V2 = 'AB';`

Comment: How would i Select those variables then? i tried it with Select '@V2', '@V1' which did not give me any result but an syntax error. Yes it is SQL Server. Thanks so far. Whiteout the ' but otherwise stack would think i want to mention a person in my post

Comment: `SELECT @V1;` will give you the value of `@V1`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad58a0c550191bc9d13affeabbe12f48)

Comment: So i was playing with your input and know i always get a popup window where i need to press ignore. Any chance of getting rid of that? or does i still missing something? i did update my question above and added a screenshot

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with DBeaver to advise on that; I stick to SSMS and ADS for SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Execute SQL Script (Alt+X) command to process multiple statements.

```
@set test1 = 'Foo' 
@set test2 = 'Bar'
select :test1, :test2
```

Explained here: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2244#issuecomment-333441954